# Use google apps script to insert rows specifically after a row containing a certain value in column XXX

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tIYnuJU1t3tl0kk4nTqNB7zj4ndXM6R2PpujDao8Uwc/edit#gid=0) that will insert new rows, triggerd by a dropdown menu selection.
The purpose of this is to add new steps to an existing list of steps, based on the qualities indicated by my dropdown menus.

Here is my current script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedValue = e.value
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet()
  var editedCell = editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, editedCol)
  var editedSheetName = editedSheet.getName()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited value = "+editedValue+", edited row = "+editedRow+", edited column = "+editedCol)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited sheet name = "+editedSheet.getName()+", the edited cell Range = "+editedCell.getA1Notation())

  // test for edit on sheet:"Input", in Column:A and value:"tiger"
  if (editedSheetName !== "Input" || editedCol !== 1 || editedValue !== "tiger") {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: INVALID edit: sheet <> input &/or col <> 1 &/or value <>tiger")
    return
  } else {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: VALID edit: sheet = input & col = 1 & value =tiger")
    // insert blank rows
    editedSheet.insertRowsAfter(editedRow, 3);
    // insert process description steps (2 columns to the right)
    var steps = [["has stripes"], ["is orange and black"], ["has sharp teeth"]]
    var person = [["pattern checker"], ["color checker"], ["teeth checker"]]
    var shapes = [["Start"], ["Start"], ["Start"]]
    editedCell.offset(1, 2, 3).setValues(steps)
    editedCell.offset(1, 6, 3).setValues(person)
    editedCell.offset(1, 5, 3).setValues(shapes)
    // delete validation for the new rows
    editedSheet.getRange(3, 1, 3).setDataValidation(null)
  }
}
```

It currently inserts the rows and their information relative to where the dropdown menu is positioned using the variables `editedRow`, `editedCell`, etc.

But I need it to insert the rows after a row that I specify by the step name. (The values in column C are the names of all the steps.)
This is because I need to add in certain new steps after other existing steps, to expound on the workflow process in the correct order. As dropdown selections are made, new and more specific steps are added into the workflow at the appropriate places.

I'm not very good at writing these scripts yet so after looking around at similar solutions my best guess was something along the lines of replacing `editedrow` with this:
`var getrowindex = getRange(1, 1, getLastRow(), 1).getValues();   for(var i = 0; i < getrowindex.length; i++){ if(getrowindex[i] == "First step"){ Logger.log(getrowindex[i]) } }`

I tried searching through previous questions but it looks like they all use different languages...

Any tips appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `a row that I specify by the value in column C.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike, sorry for not being more clear! Column C has steps listed like "Step 1", "Step 2", etc. I want to tell my script to insert the new rows after the step I say. For example, I want to be able to insert "step 2a" and "step 2b" after "Step 2" specifically. Let me know if that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a handy function to find the row which contains a unique value. Just pass the sheet and desired value and get the row containing the text back.

```
function getRowForText(sheet,text){
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet)
  var findText = range.createTextFinder(text).findAll();
  return findText[0].getRow();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I was able to incorporate into my script and replace ```insertRowsAfter(editedRow, 3)``` with ```insertRowsAfter(getRowForText(sheet,text), 3)``` and it places the new rows in the right place! But, now the script does not place the information in the new rows (they are blank) and the ```setDataValidation(null)``` does not work either. This is because it places the information in the new rows relative to the dropdown menu's position using ```editedCell.offset()```. I was not able to figure out how to use the new ```getRowForText``` function to help adjust this.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the solution I came to here, thanks to David's help!

It worked after I defined the `baseStep` I wanted the new rows to be inserted after and then changed `editedCell.offset()` to `editedSheet.getRange(getRowForText(baseStep), 1).offset()`

Switching around the location of the dropdowns made things much simpler (see the [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tIYnuJU1t3tl0kk4nTqNB7zj4ndXM6R2PpujDao8Uwc/edit#gid=0) again).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedValue = e.value
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet()
  var editedCell = editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, editedCol)
  var editedSheetName = editedSheet.getName()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited value = "+editedValue+", edited row = "+editedRow+", edited column = "+editedCol)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited sheet name = "+editedSheet.getName()+", the edited cell Range = "+editedCell.getA1Notation())

function getRowForText(text){
  var findText = editedSheet.createTextFinder(text).findAll();
  return findText[0].getRow();
}

  if (editedSheetName == "Input" && editedRow == 1 && editedValue == "yellow") {
    var baseStep = "First step"
    var numberofRows = 3
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: VALID edit: sheet = input & col = 1 & value =tiger")
    // insert blank rows
    editedSheet.insertRowsAfter(getRowForText(baseStep), numberofRows);
    // insert process description steps (2 columns to the right)
    var steps = [["light yellow"], ["orange yellow"], ["dark yellow"]]
    var person = [["light marker"], ["orange marker"], ["dark marker"]]
    var shapes = [["Start"], ["Start"], ["Start"]]
    editedSheet.getRange(getRowForText(baseStep), 1).offset(1, 1, 3).setValues(steps)
    editedSheet.getRange(getRowForText(baseStep), 1).offset(1, 5, 3).setValues(person)
    editedSheet.getRange(getRowForText(baseStep), 1).offset(1, 4, 3).setValues(shapes)
    // delete validation for the new rows
    //editedSheet.getRange(getRowForText(baseStep)+1, editedCol, numberofRows).setDataValidation(null)
  }

  // test for edit on sheet:"Input", in Column:A and value:"tiger"
  if (editedSheetName == "Input" && editedRow == 1 && editedValue == "tiger") {
    var baseStep = "Last step"
    var numberofRows = 3
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: VALID edit: sheet = input & col = 1 & value =tiger")
    // insert blank rows
    editedSheet.insertRowsAfter(getRowForText(baseStep), numberofRows);
    // insert process description steps (2 columns to the right)
    var steps = [["has stripes"], ["is orange and black"], ["has sharp teeth"]]
    var person = [["pattern checker"], ["color checker"], ["teeth checker"]]
    var shapes = [["Start"], ["Start"], ["Start"]]
    editedSheet.getRange(getRowForText(baseStep), 1).offset(1, 1, 3).setValues(steps)
    editedSheet.getRange(getRowForText(baseStep), 1).offset(1, 5, 3).setValues(person)
    editedSheet.getRange(getRowForText(baseStep), 1).offset(1, 4, 3).setValues(shapes)
    // delete validation for the new rows
    //editedSheet.getRange(getRowForText(baseStep)+1, editedCol, numberofRows).setDataValidation(null)
  };

//editedSheet.getRange("A2:A").sort({ column : 1, ascending: false });

}
```